# A question on continuous functions

Tags: functions

How can we can we(or can we?)  construct two continuous real valued functions defined over the whole real line that agree at integers only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\sin\pi x$ and $-\sin\pi x$.

Answer (score 5):

Another proposition :

Let $f$ a continuous functions, define :

$$g(x) = f(x) + \frac 1 K \sin(\pi x)$$

The constant $K$ can be used to modify the distance between the two functions.

Answer (score 2):

Without any more conditions, $f(x)=0$ and

$g(x)=\begin{cases} \{x\} & ,\{x\}\leq \frac{1}{2}\\ 1-\{x\} &, \frac{1}{2}<\{x\}<1 \end{cases}$

seem to work, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. Are you perhaps demanding something more from the desired example?

Comment: Is $[x]$ the fractional part of $x$? It would be better to indicate this in your answer since $[x]$ refers to numerous related functions.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll edit that in.

Comment: Also, your example is the [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) with frequency of $1$ and amplitude of $0.5$. So it can be given the simpler formula of $\left|x-\left\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor \right|$.

Comment: Initially I wanted to say that any appropriate tent function works, but this is the simplest one that popped to mind, and the simplest expression that I had.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as finding a continuous function that cancels at integers only. Say

$$\sin(\pi x)(\cos(5x)+2).$$

[image]